# Stack Overflow future features

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Due to wide spread popularity of stackoverflow.com among programmers, nowadays one can find 
the list of features that programmer would like to see on Stack Overflow.
Some are genuine and some are jokes.

One such joke I found says:

> Stackoverflow.com will introduce a new
>   software testing service inspired by
>   Amazon's Mechanical Turk, where
>   developers upload their programs and
>   testers find bugs in exchange for a
>   micropayment. Somebody then does the
>   obvious and connects it to a
>   Mechanical Turk task that gets one
>   bunch of monkeys to write code and
>   uses the second bunch to test it. A
>   reasonably good clone of Windows 7 is
>   banged out over 8 months with a budget
>   of about $4,000

I would be interesting to know your feature.

Comment: should be migrated to meta SO

Comment: I'm not really sure if i understand the question...

Comment: There's no way you could keep even *one* monkey for 8 months for only $4000. And you'd need at least two for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

What's my feature? I don't know if I have just one, but I've been told I'm a talented programmer with a keen eye for spotting bugs and refactoring old code into new good code. I pick up new technologies quickly and can incorporate new ideas into my designs rapidly.

Wait, what was the question again?

Answer (score 0):

[Corbomite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Corbomite_Maneuver). Stack Exchange needs a corbomite device. It's the only way to defend the reputation / anti-reputation reactor. I'm using a prototype version on this answer, actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the list of upcoming features [by searching for the planned tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned).

See also "[Where's the list of upcoming features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40466/wheres-the-list-of-upcoming-features)."