# Where's the list of upcoming features?

Tags: discussion, feature-list

Awhile back I remember it was possible to give your limited number of votes for one or another proposed feature.
And it was a nice easy scrollable list of all the suggested features.
Does that still exist?

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37844/interesting-stackoverflow-searches/37847#37847

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are probably thinking about the [Stackoverflow Uservoice page](https://web.archive.org/web/20090506031839/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general?).  MSO [now replaces Uservoice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-meta-stackoverflow-com-replace-uservoice-com).  Use the tagging system here to find different combinations of feature requests and bugs:

- [Features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=feature-request&sort=votes&pagesize=50)
- [Bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=bug&sort=votes&pagesize=50)
- [Planned Features/bug fixes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-planned&sort=votes&pagesize=50)
- [Features/bugs under review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status-review&sort=votes&pagesize=50)
- [Features/bugs with any kind of status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=status%7E&sort=votes&pagesize=50)

Comment: Ha, I bet you're right.  I'd forgotten about the limited number of votes and nice list attributes of that service.  It's not half bad - at least it forced them to complete or close highly rated requests, where here they may linger forever without official comment.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+status-planned

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the service is here:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090219112537/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/)

However, as noted on the service itself, it has been replaced with a stackoverflow-like site here:

http://meta.stackoverflow.com

The list of highest voted requests is here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request

The list of highest votes requests that haven't been implemented and aren't declined is here:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+-status-completed+-status-declined+-status-bydesign