# Can the public track feature-requests via a view into the SO ticket tracker?

Tags: feature-request, support, tracking

This other [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18130/add-the-open-feature-requests-view-to-the-list-of-available-views-on-meta) seems mildly related, but not really.

Where can the [M]?S[UOF] community see whether features we've requested or bugs we've reported are being actively tracked and/or are in process?

Can we even see those? If not, I'm requesting to be able to :)

Comment: Not dupes, but see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33483/stack-overflow-future-features/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40466/wheres-the-list-of-upcoming-features

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/filters/380524/feature-request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) tag is probably the closest thing to a list you're going to find. Of course, you may also want to check the [Bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=bugs) and [Reqs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=requests) tabs on the front page of meta, which show what hasn't been declined. Unfortunately, there's no way at this point to see the internal bug tracker.

Comment: that's a shame :-|   ..it'd be really really nice to know what direction the sites are taking